# Owncloud Task caldav url

Tags: owncloud, caldav, nextcloud

im able to sync owncloud calendar events to my php app with the 
url:  `owncloud/remote.php/caldav/calendar/admin/personal`. I want to sync owncloud tasks  also, what is the url for tasks ?

Answer (score 2):

The same URLs are used for tasks, as calendars are automatically tasklists. You do not need the tasks app enabled.

The same is true for nextCloud.

Answer (score 1):

It could be that you need the [**Tasks**](https://apps.owncloud.com/content/show.php?content=164356) app enabled in ownCloud. But this app not working anymore in ownCloud 9!

The workaround is:

```
sudo -u www-data bash
cd /var/www/owncloud/apps
rm -rf tasks/
git clone https://github.com/owncloud/tasks tasks
cd tasks
git checkout DAVclient
```

This enables Tasks again. And now you should be able to get the Tasks **list** via the usual **caldav link** you have pasted above.

Sadly I cannot simply test it in the browser. I'm using calendar and tasks with Lightning in Thunderbird and there I just need to give him the caldav link to get calendar and tasks as well. I think you are just missing the way to get the data. The url should be the same as already said.

Does it work?

Comment: not using commandline, i removed the tasks folder, downloaded from https://github.com/owncloud/tasks , extracted, renamed to tasks, copied in apps. but i cannot run 'git checkout DAVclient' as the server is not allowed internet connection,

Comment: enabled tasks , when i open tasks,  shows server error 500

Comment: Well could you show your console output. And maybe could you show how you accessed the the caldav calendar. Maybe I can see the issue from there. You need to set the credentials somewhere right? I'm also interested in this so let's do this :)